# Read Oracle DB FROM Microsoft SQL Server Manager 2012 to find Unknown Table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle

I am working on a project that requires me to read/write to an OLEDB. I do not know what table the information I'm looking for is in and there are about 150+ tables. Is there a way to search each table for a certain column header without querying each table one by one? so far I've just been doing

```
SELECT * FROM [name]..[name].[name] GO
```

And reading the headers in data grid view on a vb.net program I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you have a user with dba privileges on the Oracle database.

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
 FROM sys.dba_tab_columns
WHERE column_name LIKE UPPER('%Your column name%');
```